# Dejavu - Audio Fingerprinting in Python

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, audio, audio-fingerprinting

I have installed all dependencies as requested in the https://github.com/worldveil/dejavu/blob/master/INSTALLATION.md

I am using Ubuntu 14.4 I am new to Linux.

I installed MYSQLDB and created a database called 'dejavu'. When I run this command in Terminal I got the following errors.

```
> paul@paul-HP-Pavilion-dv6700-Notebook-PC:~/dejavu$ python dejavu.py
> --recognize mic 10 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "dejavu.py", line 64, in <module>
>     djv = init(config_file)   File "dejavu.py", line 31, in init
>     return Dejavu(config)   File "/home/paul/dejavu/dejavu/__init__.py", line 28, in __init__
>     self.db.setup()   File "/home/paul/dejavu/dejavu/database_sql.py", line 158, in setup
>     with self.cursor() as cur:   File "/home/paul/dejavu/dejavu/database_sql.py", line 322, in cursor
>     return Cursor(**options)   File "/home/paul/dejavu/dejavu/database_sql.py", line 345, in __init__
>     conn = mysql.connect(**options)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in
> Connect
>     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187,
> in __init__
>     super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
> _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
```

I am guessing it is something to do with the way I have Dejavu linked or not linked to my Database.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: They have a short tutorial here:  https://github.com/worldveil/dejavu#fingerprinting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like you have a password set for your MySQL database, and the default dejavu config specifies no password.

To run the examples, you need to change the `dejavu.cnf.SAMPLE` file with the settings of your MySQL database:

```
{
    "database": {
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "user": "root",
        "passwd": "<root_password>",
        "db": "dejavu"
    }
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated kraterrak.